# Select and Insert Large Amount of Data using Sqlite3 and Python

Tags: python, sql, select, sqlite, insert

I am using python to create set of string and trying to find if that string is in the sqlite table. If it is, I will insert it to another table. However using one "LIKE" operator for every string value takes too much time. So I tried to combine every string that i want to search in to one SELECT

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ID, str0, str1, str2, str3) 
SELECT m.ID, m.str0, m.str1, m.str3, 2 FROM table2 m 
WHERE m.str0 LIKE "%xyz%" OR m.str0 LIKE "%asd%" OR m.str0 LIKE "%qwe%" ..... 
(goes on and on and on and on)
```

Using execute() in one single INSERT created an error that query should be less than 1000 char.

Created a list that is l = [%xyz%, %asd%, %qwe%] and tried to use executemany()

```
conn.executemany('INSERT INTO table1 (ID, str0, str1, str2, str3) 
SELECT m.ID, m.str0, m.str1, m.str2, 2 FROM table 2 m 
WHERE m.str0 LIKE ?',l)
```

but it gave an error which is "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied."

What would be the best way to deal with such task?

Comment: You could create a temp table and throw all words to match in there.  Then use `LIKE` against that table.  If you need an example, I can post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

`executemany` is expecting a list of lists to be passed to the function. Instead of a one dimensional list, use two dimensions. Also, note that you are inserting five values into the database i.e "(ID, str0, str1, str2, str3)", where as three are provided in the list. Try adding more values:

```
l = [[%xyz%, %asd%, %qwe%, %something%, %somethingelse%]]
```

Comment: This query does not expect 3 parameters.

Comment: @CL. thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: This query does not expect 5 parameters.

Comment: @CL. could you clarify?

Comment: The thing is I am not adding values from list. insert values comes from the original table row. I am using list only for select if i understand you right.

Comment: This query expects one parameter, so `l` must be a list containing one-element lists.

Answer (score -1):

For cases like this you should use `IN` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table.str0 IN ('str1', 'str2', 'str3'); // With match any rows where str0 equals any of the passed values ('str1', 'str2', 'str3')
```

You can read more about it [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm).